# node_modules directory on the server in vue/cli app?

Tags: vuejs2

After I deployed @vue/cli 4.0.5 app on server(apache hosting under ubuntu)
I noticed node_modules directory in the app and wonder do we need it on server ?

In .gitignore I have lines :

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist

.env.development
.env.production
```

both locally and on server

For deploy I run command:

```
npm run build
```

After I added new package in the project, I have to run on server

```
npm install
```

It it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, Yes and Yes

Long answer:
Yes, the node_modules has to be both in your dev and production environment. It's in that folder all of the vendor/packages files are stored.

You never git this folder, because the `npm install` will automatically install all the needed packages according to the `package-lock.json` file.

And yes, for each package you add, you have to run `npm install`, to actually download the new package, and to get an update lock file, which will be comitted.